# Google Play Store warning about fewer devices supported by updated APK

Tags: android

In the latest version of my app I updated the manifest file to include support for ICS version. When activating the APK file, I got a warning (that I apparently ignored) about newest version supports fewer devices than previous version. Later that day I saw couple of posts in forums where user saying that they are getting APP incompatible with their device messages. 
The current info in manifest looks like this:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="15"
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

The previous version in manifest had following info

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="14"
    android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

I used targetSDK as 14 to enable action bar. 
Any idea why this would lead to fewer device support though the maxSDK is 15 instead of 14?
Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

First:

Check if you added any new permissions which limited the number of devices, such as `'android.hardware.touchscreen` permission.

"The APK you set as active has new features / permissions that prevent it
from running on some devices that you previously supported. As such, those
devices that are no longer supported due to your update will not receive
the update, since they don't support it."

Next:

Try to remove your `targetSdkVersion` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Then you can try to add the file `project.properties` in the same directory level of `AndroidManifest.xml` with the content:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Project target.
target=android-14
```

Comment: No other changes except adding android:targetSdkVersion="14" and changing android:maxSdkVersion to 15 from 14.

Comment: See my modification of the answer. I guess you can try to have a `project.properties` file yourself or try to change the sdk version by right click of the project, then this file will be generated automatically.

Comment: If I remove the target sdk from the manifest, I loose the action bar overflow and also not able to use the halo theme. Per Android Dev blog http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html need to specify the targetSDK as 14 in manifest file. Also for halo theme to work, targetSDK has to be 11 or higher.

Comment: Did you try it? I think the `project.properties` or `ant.properties` is same. Please tell me which IDE you are using?

Comment: Yea, I did try it and confirmed halo theme and action bar did not work as expected because of not specifying targetSDK. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to confirm based on my users response that only folks who had custom ROM got the incompatible message, but were later able to get the update from the market. So most likely an issue for users with custom ROM only and not related to android:targetSdkVersion as I suspected earlier.